# python3.4 file open process clears file instead of updating file

Tags: python, regex, file

I am trying to open a file and look for an entry. if the entry/string is there/exist, delete all eight lines associated with that string. Then add a fresh record/entry into the file.

Right now my code just clears the entire file (empties the file)

I have tried to farther indent the fd.write portion deeper in to the loop and also remove it from the loop, I either produce an empty file or flood the file with hundreds of entries.

code:

```
name = 'domain1'
with open("/usr/local/etc/list.db") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as fd:
        for line in f:
                if name in line:
                        list(islice(f, 8))
                fd.write("zone \""+name+"\" {\n")
                fd.write("  type slave;\n")
                fd.write("  masters {10.10.10.2;};\n")
                fd.write("  allow-notify{10.10.10.2;};\n")
                fd.write("  allow-transfer {trusted;};\n")
                fd.write("  key-directory \"/usr/local/etc/namedb/\";\n")
                fd.write("  file \"/usr/"+name+".signed\";\n")
                fd.write("};")
move(fd.name,"/usr/local/etc/list.db")
print(fd)
fd.close()
```

file contents before script:

```
zone "domain2.com" {
  type slave;
  masters {10.10.10.2;};
  allow-notify{10.10.10.2;};
  allow-transfer {trusted;};
  key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
  file "/usr/domain.signed";
};
```

expected output:

```
zone "domain1.com" {
  type slave;
  masters {10.10.10.2;};
  allow-notify{10.10.10.2;};
  allow-transfer {trusted;};
  key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
  file "/usr/domain.signed";
};
zone "domain2.com" {
  type slave;
  masters {10.10.10.2;};
  allow-notify{10.10.10.2;};
  allow-transfer {trusted;};
  key-directory "/usr/local/etc/namedb/";
  file "/usr/domain.signed";
};
```

how do I get my python3 code to update the file without clearing it?

Comment: you're not performing `fd.write()` in the loop, so only one output will be written.

Comment: @monkut  when I put it inside the loop, I get a bunch of domain1 entries.

Comment: @monkut if I put it inside the if statement inside the loop, I get a completely empty file.   o.0

Comment: where are you defining `name`?  You perform `if name in line:` check, but don't show where name is defined.

Comment: Your code never changes the value of `name` and your code can only write once to the file since it's not inside a loop. I think there's more code that you're not showing us.

Comment: @monkut  name is defined way way high about. static at the moment to 'domain1' for testing and debugging purposes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the lines in `f` to the file when you're iterating through `f` in the for loop (while skipping the lines you do not want). Something like this:

```
with open("/usr/local/etc/namedb/tmp/zonelist.db") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as fd:
        skip = False
        for line in f:      
            if name in line:
                    skip = True
            if line.strip() == "};" and skip is True:
                    skip = False
                    continue
            elif skip is True:
                    continue
            fd.write(line)
        fd.write("zone \""+name+"\" {\n")
        fd.write("  type slave;\n")
        fd.write("  masters {10.10.10.2;};\n")
        fd.write("  allow-notify{10.10.10.2;};\n")
        fd.write("  allow-transfer {trusted;};\n")
        fd.write("  key-directory \"/usr/local/etc/namedb/\";\n")
        fd.write("  file \"/usr/local/etc/signed\";\n")
        fd.write("};\n")
move(fd.name,"/usr/local/etc/namedb/tmp/zonelist.db")
print(fd)
fd.close()
```

Right now, you're only ever writing the new entry to `fd`, hence why it looks like all the old entries are "deleted" (they're just not written).

So what the for loop does is if it sees the name (which I assume is the first line of the entry), it'll set a boolean flag to true which will skip all lines till we see a "};" on a line by itself (you could change this to be `line.startswith("};")` if it isn't always going to be on a line by itself), at which point the flag will get set back to false. Whenever the flag is false, it'll write that line of `f` to the temporary file. Once all lines of `f` are either written/ignored to the temp file, then we move onto the new entry for the file.

Comment: I have tried a few different methods, either with or without the temporary file (which is very much needed). file never writes  https://bpaste.net/show/481f27ec7a6b

Comment: the code has a bug. If I add domain1 it adds it. If I then add domain2, it also add it. but if I try and add domain1 again, it clears domain2, then domain1 is the only domain in the file.